# Label with different font sizes

Tags: winforms, label

Basically I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

but I have no idea how to do it, I tried with 2 labels to combine them but the result isn't that great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the text from a different point of view, namely, the baseline:

```vb
Public Class MyLabel
  Inherits Label

  <Browsable(False)> _
  Public Overrides Property AutoSize As Boolean
    Get
      Return False
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
      'MyBase.AutoSize = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    'MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    Dim fromLine As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Height * 0.75
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim fontParts() As String = Me.Text.Split(".")
    Using bigFont As New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 20)
      TextRenderer.DrawText(g, fontParts(0), bigFont, _
                            New Point(0, fromLine - GetBaseLine(bigFont, g)), _
                            Me.ForeColor, Color.Empty)
      If fontParts.Length > 1 Then
        Dim bigWidth As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, fontParts(0), bigFont, _
                                                           Point.Empty, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding).Width
        Using smallFont As New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 8)
          TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "." & fontParts(1), smallFont, _
                                New Point(bigWidth + 3, fromLine - GetBaseLine(smallFont, g)), _
                                Me.ForeColor, Color.Empty)
        End Using
      End If
    End Using
  End Sub

  Private Function GetBaseLine(fromFont As Font, g As Graphics) As Single
    Dim fontHeight As Single = fromFont.GetHeight(g)
    Dim lineSpacing As Single = fromFont.FontFamily.GetLineSpacing(fromFont.Style)
    Dim cellAscent As Single = fromFont.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(fromFont.Style)
    Return fontHeight * cellAscent / lineSpacing
  End Function

End Class
```

The code basically measures the height of the font from a line.  In my example, I used the bottom 25% of the Label's client space to say, start drawing from this line: `Me.ClientSize.Height * 0.75`.

For each font you use, you would have to measure that font's baseline and subtract that from your drawing line in order to offset your drawing position of the text.

Measuring an individual character's dimensions is not easy due to aliasing and glyph overhangs. I added a small padding between the big text and the small text: `bigWidth + 3` to try to make it look good.  If the big number ends in a 7, the distance looks a little off because the stem of the 7 is angled.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class inherited from Label, and override the *void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)* method to change the default rendering behavior:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("A", Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), 10, 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("B", new Font(Font.FontFamily, 20), new SolidBrush(ForeColor), 50, 10);
    }
}
```

As a result, "B" will be two times larger the "A". You can achieve your goal in the same way, but you have to calculate the position of your sub-strings ("145", ".", "54") and draw them.

Comment: Fonts and Brushes are `IDisposable` and should be put inside a `using(...) {}` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use devexpress `LabelControl.AllowHtmlString` property to true and use the supported `<size>` tag within the `LabelControl`'s Text property as detailed in the HTML Text Formatting documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use user control WPF in windows form. to do that do this step.
1. add user control to the windows form
2.from xml of usercontrol name grid like t1
3. add this function to the usercontrol.wpf.cs

```
public void Actor(string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<TextBlock   xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
                    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'> ");
    sb.Append(text);
    sb.Append(@"</TextBlock>");
    TextBlock myButton = (TextBlock)XamlReader.Parse(sb.ToString());
    this.t1.Children.Clear();
    t1.Children.Add(myButton);
}
```

4. after that from form1.css add this function in every where you want.

```
              userControl11.Actor("<Run Text='Hi ' FontWeight='Bold'/><Run Text='Hitler ' FontWeight='Bold'/>");
    userControl11.Actor(" < Run FontWeight = 'Bold' FontSize = '14' Text = 'This is WPF TextBlock Example. ' />");
```

you can mange the write code "" of Actor function by using xml wpf.